# SQL query to update a column to be foreignId and onDelete Cascade

Tags: sql, laravel, cpanel

I'm working on a live laravel website on cPanel and I'd like to update the `user_id` column on the `properties` table to be `foreignId` and `onDelete Cascade`.

I have tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE properties
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_properties_user
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But it's not working(deleting a user doesn't delete its associated property) and I'm getting the following response when I execute the command above:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.1913 seconds.)

ALTER TABLE properties ADD CONSTRAINT fk_properties_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Works fine with MySQL 5.5, https://dbfiddle.uk/zCV7e9VB. But I remember even older versions cheated. Which version are you using? `select version();`

Comment: @jarlh, I'm using version 8 and it's working with version 8 from your demo. I'm not sure why it's not working in phpMyAdmin!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a migration file:

```
php artisan make:migration add_fk_to_properties_table --table=properties
```

Then, with `->change()` method do like this:

```
Schema::table('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->change(); 
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

At last, migrate the file

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: It's shared hosting, using cpanel I don't have access to the terminal to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Alphy Gacheru Try this answer on the localhost database before doing it live website.

Comment: That will work, my challenge is how to do it on Cpanel as the database already has data that should be preserved and I can't run migrations there.

Comment: @AlphyGacheru, You mean you don't have access to a terminal or you don't know how to do it ?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru, there is a terminal on cpanel as I am also using cPanel for my website but you have to navigate to your project root directory in order to run the artisan command. Recommend you to create a backup of your database stuff before doing this.

Comment: Thanks, I will back up. I thought I can't use it. How do I navigate to the root directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254024/discussion-between-js-tech-and-alphy-gacheru).